# Young Adult book series about humanoid dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, books, dinosaurs

I read a book series about 15 years ago. It’s about these humanoid dinosaurs, I think the covers were red, green and blue, one of the main characters was a triceratops. And I think the flying and swimming dinosaurs had disappeared and where believed to have died out.

They also had like coloured armour and weapons.

I think each cover was a different colour and had a circle in the middle with one of the dinosaurs in it wearing coloured armour and holding a weapon to match.

I also think that the three dinosaurs were in a castle or something, and they found statues of flying dinosaurs.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Are there any extra details you could [edit] in to your question? Take a look at [Tips for asking Story Identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337) for some helpful prompts.

Answer (score 4):

There are some elements that ring a bell, but definitely others that are not compatible.

However, I give you **The Quintaglio Ascension** by Robert J. Sawyer.

- Three books, a little more than 15 years ago, and one paperback edition did have red, blue and *yellow* (**not** green) covers in a French edition, with a circle and a dinosaur in it. A similar circle was used in the [Italian edition](https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07Q43QQKR). They were different dinosaurs, even if, in the story, only two "races" of dinosaurs appear and they're both theropods.
- Flying and swimming dinosaurs extinct. Check.
- Main character a triceratops - **nope**. One character has a sort of extra bony prong but that's all; they're related to *Nanotyrannus*.
- Character on the cover holding an *object* (never a weapon), yes.
- Characters in a castle - there are several "castles" in the story, and the "destiny" of an extinct race *is* somewhat discovered, but that race is not one of either flying or swimming dinosaurs.

This is a different cover, but it has similarities with the paperback one.

[image: Covers of "The Quintaglio Ascension" series by Robert J. Sawyer. A green dinosaur with a bandolier-like sash performs activities, holding tools such as a telescope and a hammar, while large planets and moons are visible in the sky behind.]

Comment: It would be good if you could track down the covers with the circles because I don't remember ever seeing those, and ISFDb doesn't know about them.  (Which doesn't mean they don't exist, just that they're not widely-known.)

Comment: @DavidW my bad: I was describing a French edition I saw in Nice about 2006 or 2007, I think. I own copies of the Italian and the English editions (the English one is the same as the pictures above). Of course, the "circle" depends on the edition, and is not part of the cover art; I should have made this clearer. Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: No these unfortunately aren’t the books I’m looking for :(